# Eclipse shorcuts (F3/ctrl+click) not working for navigation

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu-12.04

Shortcut to access the declaration with the help of this shortcut is not working
Installed version of Ubuntu is 12.04
and for Eclipse it is:
Version: Juno Release
Build id: 20120614-1722

It says:- The Resource is not on the include path of a JavaScript project

It works with .jsp files but not with .js files !

Comment: If so, it doesn't even mention what language it's for.

Comment: Eclipse shorcuts (F3/ctrl+click) not working for navigation in ubuntu 12.04

Comment: for me it does work. Using Helios.

Comment: can u please elaborate a bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These shotcuts works well with this [version](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/junor) installed.